# How can I create a RNG command in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, command

So I'm making a discord bot and want to add a random number generator commands that allows the user to specify the least and greatest numbers. This is what I've tried so far:

```
@bot.command
async def rng(ctx):
    await ctx.send(random.randiant(1, 10))
```

I would like to make a command like this:

```
$rng 1,10
```

The $ is the prefix, the command name is rng and it specipies the least and greatest number. All comments and answers are appreciated. Please help me :(

Comment: It sounds like you're just asking how to send parameters in a discord command, is that right?

Comment: I guess yeah. But if you could help that'd be great.

Comment: I gave you a link to a question that shows how to do it.